# How to define composition(boss, subordinate relationship)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, uml

I would like to define recurrent composition relationship. If the boss is removed from the system all his subordinates are removed by cascade update.

By this I mean:

[image]

How should I state it in the code?

```
public class Person{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public virtual Person Person {get;set}
}
```

Is that possible in the Entity Framework?

Comment: In my opinion a 1:n association is too rigid to describe associations between persons. Can't anybody *ever* happen to have two bosses? If you make this many-to-many you'd only have to remove junction records.

Comment: @GertArnold That's just an sscce, the real problem is different.

Comment: This model says that every person always has a boss. Are you sure that's true?

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented anywhere as far as I know, but **Entity Framework only creates / updates / deletes entities it has loaded**.

So if you load a `Person` and delete it, you'll get a foreign key violation error if this `Person` has subordinates. EF won't update these child records (set their FKs to null) automatically.

If however you load a `Person` *and* its subordinates and delete the `Person`, EF will nullify each child's foreign key.

To make this loading a bit easier, you should modify the `Person` class slightly:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Boss { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Boss")] // Use one FK field for Boss and Subordinates 
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Subordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can load a `Person` and `Include()` its `Subordinates`.

By the way, you can't specify cascaded delete/update rules because Sql Server doesn't accept cyclic cascade paths.